# twitter iphone integration: Access token already used

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

In myapp,

I have registered my app on twitter.

I am using Twitter-Oauth Library.

When I am sign in to twitter it shows me the message in orange dialog box.

that `"your page is not valid.It looks like someone already used your token information..."`

I have pasted the consumer key and secret key in my application.

I dont know what could be the issu.

Comment: it sucks. I am getting this error frequently..